# Extending AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler, Remembering destination URL

Tags: grails, spring-security

Grails 1.3.7
Spring-Security-Core 1.1.2

I've implemented a custom class that extends AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler so that specific roles can be taken to specific URL's after logging in which works great.  However, if the session expires I need to be able to take the user to the requested URL when the session expired, overriding the Role based URL.

Here is a simplified version of my code

```
class MyAuthSuccessHandler extends AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
                                      final Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

    def goAdmin = false
    authentication.authorities.each { ga ->
      if (ga.authority.equals('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        goAdmin = true
      }
    }

    if (goAdmin) {
      response.sendRedirect(request.contextPath + '/admin/index')
    }else{
      super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication)
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding a call to determineTargetUrl(request, response) but it always returns '/' even though I've requested a resource like /admin/foo which is protected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting

```
super.determineTargetUrl(request, response);
```

should work, if you use `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` as super class. I am not sure if it is possible for you to switch to this class in your scenario. Maybe this can help, but I guess you are fully aware of it: http://omarello.com/2011/09/grails-custom-target-urls-after-login/

Comment: And yet, it doesn't.  SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler is the super class of AjaxAware.....  That method is actually buried in the abstract super class that is about 4 levels up the chain anyway.  So it shouldn't matter which class I extend, as long as it is one of them.